# how to create inputs having the name as decoded_sample_data:0 and decoded_sample_data:1

Tags: tensorflow

I want to create inputs having the name as `decoded_sample_data:0` and `decoded_sample_data:1` in tensorflow. I used the placeholder as follows:

```
sample_placeholder = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[16000,1],name='decoded_sample_data') 
sr_placeholder = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, name='decoded_sample_data')
```

But the names are `decoded_sample_data:0` and `decoded_sample_data_1:0`.

How can I create the same names with different index. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, unless both tensors are generated by the same operation. The name of a Tensor is the concatenation of (i) the name of the operation that produced it, (ii) a colon (:), and (iii) the index of that tensor in the outputs of the operation that produced it. In other words, tensorflow only names your tensors with the same name and a different index at the end (:0, :1, etc) when they are both outputs of the same operation. This works in situations like the following:

```
x,y=tf.nn.top_k([1], 1)
print x.name # => 'TopKV2:0'
print y.name # => 'TopKV2:1'
```

The above operation `tf.nn.top_k(...)` generated both output tensors x, and y. So they are automatically named `TopKV2:0` and `TopKV2:1` because they both come from the same `tf.nn.top_k(...)` operation. In your case, however, you are generating two variables with two different operations (as seen in your two lines of code), so Tensorflow's underlying API will not name them as `decoded_sample_data:0` and `decoded_sample_data:1`.

Comment: Thank for your response. I ask this question since the requirement from a challenge on Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/c/tensorflow-speech-recognition-challenge#Prizes. Actually, I cannot create the inputs like competition require but they have the model that handle this kind of inputs